# little doubt regarding the past simple and present perfect

Tags: grammar

I'm an English Learner. I have written a sentence below in order to fix my doubt.
If I have to talk about a past experience is it better to write:

1. "I **worked** in the old factory from 2010 to 2015"

or

2. "I **have worked** in the old factory from 2010 to 2015"?

Which is the right sentence? 1 or 2?

In my opinion it's better to use the first sentence, because in the sentence I've talked regarding a specific finite time.

For example if I modify the sentence 1 as "**Last winter** I **worked** in the old factory."" I would use the simple past.

It is possible that the sentence 1 is used in American English and the sentence number 2 in British English?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The first is accurate.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh Do you think that if someone in a british or american school write the sentence 2 instead of the 1 it is considered a mistake by the teacher? just for curiosity.

Comment: 1) is correct if you no longer work there. If you do, you would say "I have worked at the factory since 2015".

Comment: @KateBunting thanks. If I currently work there I would say also "I have been working there since 2015". Am I right?

Comment: @ryuk Yes it will be considered as a mistake. Although I am no British or American myself, it is still a mistake because you are using present perfect to demonstrate something that is already over or in the past.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh thanks a lot! I've understand! Writing "from 2010 to 2015" or expressions like "last winter", "last year", "5 years ago"... means that the fact is over, so I have to use simple past! :)

Comment: @ryuk Nope wait. For 2010-15, you use the past, however you can use either past or present perfect to denote actions in time periods like _last summer_ or  _last winter_.

Comment: Yes, you could use _have been working_ as well.

Comment: For e.g. I **have worked** as a waitress since last summer/winter.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh thanks. So if I've understand well I could write also "I **have been working** as a waitress since last summer/winter" if I am currently working as waitress.

Comment: @ryuk Yes. You can say that.

Comment: thank you very much @DhanishthaGhosh! :)

Comment: Perhaps this is a British thing, but I would very strongly prefer "I have worked as a waitress since last summer" over "I worked as a waitress since last summer".  @DhanishthaGhosh When you said "you can use either past or present perfect", did you mean "either simple past or present perfect" or did you mean "either past perfect or present perfect"?  (I agree that you can use the past perfect, where it fits the sense.)

Comment: @rjpond thank you for your answer! Just for curiosity...are you american or canadian? As a learner in the sentence i prefer using the present perfect continous, for me it's clearer that now I am working as a waitress (I have been working as a waitress since last summer/winter). But maybe if I remember well sometimes in british grammar they are used or present the perfect simple or the present perfect continous.

Comment: @rjpond It depends from case to case. Just as you said. I mentioned it sensing that they can use either of them where it deems fit.

Comment: @ryuk No, I'm British.  Sorry if I was unclear.  I agree, you can say "I have worked as a waitress since last summer" or "I have been working as a waitress since last summer" - in both cases the work is ongoing.

Comment: @rjpond Crystal clear :) thanks a lot!